# Is there an EventHandler in which I can check if ListBox doesn't contain any items?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I'm trying to avoid having the same code in multiple places. Which event handler would let me to check if I have any items in my ListBox on the fly?

This is how I check if I have any items in ListBox:

```
if (lbMessage.Items.Count > 0)
{
    btnStart.Enabled = true;
}
else
{
    btnStart.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Instead of having code in multiple places could you not put it in a method and just call the method?

Comment: @Bali C, I could, but I wonder if there's any event handlers which I can use, instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no event for such an occurrence (for a list of available events, check out the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx) for this control). To make your code more re-usable, you could use a property, such as:

```
public bool ListBoxHasItems
{
    get { return lbMessage.Items.Count > 0; }
}
```

Then you can just call that property each time you want to check if there are any items.

Comment: You could even make it an extension method.